# Retaining an autoreleased variable, where do I release it?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have a NSMutableArray property declared as (nonatomic, retain) called Categories.  In dealloc, I release the memory for that variable.  Originally, in viewDidLoad, I allocated that array and called another method that populated that data with dummy data.  Basically

```
[categories addObject:someObject1];
[categories addObject:someObject2];
....
```

This was working.

Then I got the real data from a coworker in a method that talked to the model and returned an autoreleased array.  I was getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS after I used the method.

```
categories = [datamanager GetCategories];
```

Now is that because I didn't retain the autoreleased array returned from the datamanager GetCategories method?

If so, I need to delete the alloc/init in viewDidLoad since that would be a memory leak right?

Thanks, just trying to make sure I'm understanding memory mgmt correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. If you're getting `categories` from a method that returns an **autoreleased** object then you want to **retain** that object. So you can change your assignment above to either of the following:

```
// use the synthesized setter's retain
self.categories = [datamanager GetCategories];

// or explicitly retain the object (which clearly indicates the code's intention)
categories = [[datamanager GetCategories] retain];
```

The alloc/init in `viewDidLoad` is unnecessary.

Comment: I would say best practice would be to use the `self.` syntax. You've declared an Obj-C 2.0 property already, you may as well use it.

Comment: Agree with darvids0n, self.property = is always preferable to setting it directly, especially when you're overriding setters and you don't know why it's not working!

Comment: I agree `self.` syntax is preferable. However it's important for someone learning Obj-c memory management to understand how both options work.

Comment: also don't forget to release the retained categories variable in dealloc as per the original question 'Retaining an autoreleased variable, where do I release it?'